# How to catch WPF WebBrowser-Execption before crashing?

Tags: c#, wpf, error-handling, runtime-error, webbrowser-control

I am creating a WPF app which contains a WebBrowser element and a refresh button. 
After some time (may be weeks) suddenly the app crash and close itself. 
All code in the refresh button is surronded with `try` and `catch`, so if something happens I should bed logged, but how can I catch and log a WebBrowser error and prevent it from crashing?

thank's a lot

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ok lets say i dont have any code in my app just constractor, and a webbrowser element, after a while the app is crashing, and i want to see why it crushed and fix it. so i need to add some log, and try & catch, but i dont know where to put it, because the only element is webbroser